# Akeeba Kickstart Restore Site and Restrict Access

Tags: component, akeebabackup, backups

I use Akeeba Backup and Akeeba Kickstart to restore my sites and it's great. I normally backup and transfer the `.jpa` files then extract manually, not via the transfer wizard.

During the restoration process, if someone visits my site they can see the progress / wizard.

Is it possible to restrict access to my site during the restoration process? Either via `.htaccess` or similar?

Ideally I'd like to display a `503 temporarily unavailable` or similar to all visitors **except me**, I should be able to view and proceed with the restoration.

Comment: Have you investigated doing a static, ip-specific (all ips other than yours) redirect condition in htaccess?  That's what we do where I work when deploying.  Essentially, this advice: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2934755/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks I like this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Website visitors can be directed to a maintenance page at `index.html` or `index.htm` rather than any `kickstart.php` or `index.php` file as most hosts are configured to load `index.html` or `index.htm` in preference to `index.php`.

You can ensure this is the case by adding the following directive to your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
```

It won't occur to most website visitors to try browsing directly to `index.php` or `kickstart.php`.

A simple `index.html` maintenance page might look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Website Name</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika" type="text/css" />
  <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        color: #222222;
        font-family: "Signika","Arial",sans-serif;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: table;
      }
      #content {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 0 20px;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 4rem;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
      }
      p {
        color: #888888;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Website Name</h1>
      <h2>Website Offline</h2>
      <p>This website is down for maintenance.<br />Please check back again soon.</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Once the website is ready for public viewing, simply delete or rename the `index.html` or `index.htm` file.